# Boost asio on windows phone 8

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, boost, windows-phone-8, boost-asio

I have a problem while compiling boost asio on windows phone 8. Compiler can't search mswsock.h. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you post the compiler error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it can't be found because it's not there for Windows Phone.

To get it to compile you will have to remove any references to the APIs that aren't available for Windows Phone in the source code.

Only the Win32 APIs [that are listed on MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662956%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)  are supported on WP8.